# Issues with Razor helper methos. VS 2013 update 3. MVC 5.2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view-helpers

We are refactoring the MVC (version 5.1.2) project.  I have a custom helper method written in C# to dynamically build HTML and is called from the view.
Now I moved all the code from C#  into `Razor`.

I created a helper file called `Header.cshtml` under the `App_Code` directory and moved all the C# code into this helper class.

```
@helper ProHeader(object model) {

    string tablType = model.GetType().GetProperty("table_type").GetValue(model, null).ToString();
    var result = tablType.Split(new[] { "_" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


............................... HTML code goes here....................
}
```

I am getting the following error when I run the app.

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   ASP.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ProHeader>b__0(TextWriter __razor_helper_writer) in c:\solution\claw\code\Reports\MAIN\Reports\App_Code\Header.cshtml:3
   System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) +70
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.WriteTo(TextWriter writer, HelperResult content) +65
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +64
   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , _Page_Views_Shared__detailReportLayout_cshtml , Object ) +312
   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid2(CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1) +990
   ASP._Page_Views_Shared__detailReportLayout_cshtml.Execute() in c:\solution\claw\code\Reports\MAIN\Reports\Views\Shared\_detailReportLayout.cshtml:27
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +391
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +164
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +233
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer) +62
   System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass7.<RenderPageCore>b__6(TextWriter writer) +622
   System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) +70
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.WriteTo(TextWriter writer, HelperResult content) +65
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +64
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) +247
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +609
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +243
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +1160
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +638
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +827
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +64
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +177
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +1131
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +1131
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +181
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +549
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +330
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +71
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +196
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +90
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +188
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +196
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +68
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +85
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +196
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +93
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +188
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +196
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +58
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +59
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

Comment: What part of the code is hitting the null ref?

Comment: The very first line.    string tablType = model.GetType().GetProperty("table_type").GetValue(model, null).ToString();

Comment: I'd split out that line and see which method is exactly getting hit.